# How do i count paragraph from a given string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In flex,

I have a below string:

> Chocolate has become one of the most popular food types and flavors in
>   the world, and a vast number of foodstuffs involving chocolate have
>   been created. Chocolate chip cookies have become very common, and very
>   popular, in most parts of Europe and North America.
>
> Gifts of chocolate molded into different shapes have become
>   traditional on certain holidays. Chocolate is also used in cold and
>   hot beverages, to produce chocolate milk and hot chocolate.
>
> Cocoa mass was used originally in Mesoamerica both as a beverage and
>   as an ingredient in foods.

Above string contains three paragraphs. How could I count paragraph from above string ?

I have tried like this:

```
    for(var i:int = 0; i < bodyPhrases.length; i++)
     {
                var para:int = bodyPhrases.indexOf("\r\r");
                var p:String = bodyPhrases.substring(1,para);
                paraCount++;
                bodyPhrases = bodyPhrases.replace(p,"");
            }
```

It takes more loop. how to find it in a easy way.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use a regular expression:

```
var regExp:RegExp = /\r\r/g;
var paragraphCount:int = bodyPhrases.match(regExp).length;
```

and you can check that it works with:

```
trace(paragraphCount:int);
```

Useful link to learn more about RegExp: http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/regexp-regular-expressions-actionscript

Comment: It worked. But it returns value as 1. But above given string contains 3 para. how to proceed further ?                           Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, I did a small research and got an interesting peace of info. If you use Unix, use \r, Mac OS \n, Win \r\n
Here's in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them