# how do I pass a database to excel using php?

Tags: php, excel

What I am trying to do is pass my database to excel. This is what I have so far:

```
$contents = "Nombre, Dirrecion, Telefono, Categoria, Correo\n";

$query = "SELECT datos.list, datos.addr, datos.tel, datos.cat, mail.mail FROM datos RIGHT JOIN mail ON datos.id = mail.id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(!empty($row['list'])){
    $contents.=$row['list'].",";
    $contents.=$row['addr'].",";
    $contents.=$row['tel'].",";
    $contents.=$row['cat'].",";
    $contents.=$row['mail']."\n";
  }
}
$contents = strip_tags($contents);

Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='excExport".date('d-m-Y').".csv'");
print $contents;
```

It prints out the contents correctly, when I try to open excExport.csv I can't seem to find this file in my computer.

Comment: May need to us `\r\n` for it to work in windows instead of `\n`. Just did a similar thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses a combination of `\r` and `\n` for a new line so instead of `\n` use `\r\n`.
 
Example: $contents = "Nombre, Dirrecion, Telefono, Categoria, Correo `\r\n`";

Check out this link: [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

**P.S.** I'm assuming this is for windows because your using Excell, this won't work in other situations.

Comment: Was the file empty when you opened it? What is the size of the file after you download it?

Comment: I can't find the file, there is no download

Comment: Put `header('Content-type: text/plain');` as the first line in your code.

Comment: nothing changed, I still get the output from the print $contents statement. Where Do I look for the file?

Comment: Are you prompted for a download? Try to be more descriptive.

Comment: No, I am not prompted for download. Just in case it saves in another place other than my downloads folder... guess it has to download into my downloads folder first

Comment: Figured out my mistake, I didn't know I could not run this code after the code that inserts the data into the database. Seems that was the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find out why? It seems strange.