# Difference between \n and \r\n in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a script that sometimes prints a newline as `\n` and sometimes uses `\r\n`. What is the difference between the two, and is one preferable over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"\n" is the class Unix/linux style for new line.
"\r\n" is the default Windows style for line separator.
"\r" is classic Mac style for line separator.
I think "\n" is better, because this also looks good on windows, but some "\r\n" may not looks so good in some editor under linux, such as eclipse or notepad++.
If you are handling some protocols, the "\r\n" is usually required.

Comment: notepad++ is a Windows-only editor; there is no native Linux version. Apart from that, "may not look so good" is highly unspecific.

Comment: I find that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/15547292) is more concise.

Answer (score 8):

Code

```
print "\n",
print "\r",
print "\r\n",
```

gives you the following output in hex

```
0a 0d 0d 0a
```

See also answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r).