# Find word that starts at a newline

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a simple loop to delete all words from the end of a text that start with a `#` and `space`. 
AS3:

```
//   messageText is usually taken from a users input field - therefore the newline is not present in the "messageText"

var messageText = "hello world #foo lorem ipsum #findme"
while (messageText.lastIndexOf(" ") == messageText.lastIndexOf(" #")){
messageText = messageText.slice(0,messageText.lastIndexOf(" "));
}
```

How to check if the position before the `#` is not a *space* but a *newline*?
I tried this but nothing gets found:

```
while (messageText.lastIndexOf(" ") == messageText.lastIndexOf("\n#")){
messageText = messageText.slice(0,messageText.lastIndexOf(" "));
}
```

Comment: overly complicated piece of code when a simple String.split('#')[0] will get you close to the wanted result.

Comment: That would not work if a link like this is in the string or am I wrong?: `http://example.com/#contact`

Answer (score 1):

```
\n is the newline character in the Unix file definition.
\r\n is the Windows version.
\r is the OSX version.
```

See also: [this previous (dupe) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them).

First thing is I'd manually try replacing "\n" with "\r\n" and then "\r" to see if there is some other newline in use.  If so, then you just need a better search term that will match each version in one go.

A better solution might be to use Regular Expression (RegExp). You are explicitly looking for the newline character and a space after it. You could use this regex pattern to look for the start of a line with a single space:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /^\s/; 
if (yourString.search(pattern) >= 0) { ... }
```

The ^ carat character enforces that it's the start of a line. The \s is a placeholder for any whitespace character, so if you don't want to match tabs then change it to a blank space. (I'm not familiar with ActionScript specifically, but that syntax looks OK and search() will return -1 if the pattern isn't found).