# Next line is not Working in PHP file write

Tags: php

When I use `\n` for next line in PHP file write, its not working.

```
$myFile = "test.txt";
$f=fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$Data="New string 1\n";
fwrite($f, $Data);
$Data="New string 2\n";
fwrite($f,$Data);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them  Try "\r\n".

Comment: Works for me, the new line characters are in the file tests.txt when I run this code.

Comment: @curtis1000, linux user, i guess? OP is on win, i guess, too... :)

Comment: "\r\n" Worked my os was windows

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try PHP_EOL for line breaks must be platform independent