# Log.i is not showing in code

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

i write a simple code in andorid

```
package com.hello.stringtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        String x = "\r\nHello\r\nHello1\r\nHello2";
        Log.i("Hello", x);
        Toast.makeText(this,x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

when i run this application i was expecting in Log line separated
Hello
Hello1
Hello2

but there is nothing in Logcat table .can anyone please explain why it's not showing in Logcat.

Comment: You might have activated any filter on the logcat windows. (Android Studio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I try following code

```
    Log.i("ACTIVITY1", "\rCreated");
    Log.i("ACTIVITY2", "\nCreated");
```

only ACTIVITY2 appears in Logcat. I guess you issue is related to \r.
Remove \r from your String x. Try \n instead.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/4791726). \r seems to be for old Mac OS versions.

Comment: This solved my problem, thx.  I am re-directing the output of a command line tool to logcat, and I could not get it to display.  Turns out "Log" was silently throwing away my data (which had \r line endings) a simple addition of .replace("\r", "") to the String fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

That's because by default the `Log.i` takes up less priority when compared to `log.d`. TO check it out change your logcat window to info from debug here you can get a complete reference of the  priority

```
The priority is one of the following character values, ordered from lowest to highest priority:
V — Verbose (lowest priority)
D — Debug
I — Info
W — Warning
E — Error
F — Fatal
S — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)
```

also this link might be useful 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#startingLogcat