# Remove all line-breaks, but except only one break?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text sent by the user with breaklines

```
Text of example in line 1.
(break line)
(break line)
(break line)
The text is very nice...
(break line)
(break line)
The end.
```

Result expected:

```
Text of example in line 1.
The text is very nice...
The end.
```

NOT: `Text of example in line 1. The text is very nice... The end.`

How I do this in JavaScript(`str.replace`) receiving via AJAX in PHP

```
$text = strip_tags($text, '<br>');
```

---

Thank you for answers! But I tested all .. and then I went to see that my DIV is generating HTML codes, I believe that is why it is not working (RegEx). How do I ignore HTML elements to be able to text with line breaks?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex replace.

```
str = str.replace(/\n{2,}/g, "\n");
```

`{2,}` means to match 2 or more of the previous expression. So any sequence of 2 or more newlines will be replaced with a single newline.

Comment: Since you're replacing with the same char, it doesn't hurt to just replace all `str = str.replace(/\n+/g, "\n");`

Comment: @trex005 This is slightly more efficient, since it doesn't bother replacing a single newline with itself.

Comment: You are correct, drastically more efficient:
http://jsperf.com/regex-replace-multi-single

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised there's so much difference when there are no single newlines in your sample text.

Comment: In HTML, line breaks are `<br>`.

Comment: If you're working with the DOM, you shouldn't use regular expressions. Use DOM methods to remove elements.

Comment: You can also use CSS to change how the DIV is displayed.

Comment: i have this sequence: `1<br><br><br>2<br><br>3<br><br><br><br>4<br><br>5`. how do I leave only 2 `<br>`? `1<br><br>2<br><br>3<br><br>4<br><br>5`

Comment: str.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>){2,}/gi, '<br><br>'); tks ;)

Comment: You should use `{3,}`, since you don't need to replace anything when there are already only 2 copies.

Answer (score 5):

Although, the [answer by @Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35663781/2025923) is correct, it'll not work across different OS/platforms.

Different OS uses different character combination to use as linebreak.

1. Windows:    `\r\n` = CR LF
2. Unix/Linux:   `\n`   = LF
3. Mac:    `\r`   = CR

See [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

I'll suggest the following RegEx that will work across platforms.

```
str = str.replace(/(\r\n?|\n){2,}/g, '$1');
```

[**Live RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tV5aQ4/1)

**Explanation:**

1. `()`: Capturing group
2. `\r\n?`: Matches `\r` followed by `\n` optionally. Thus matches

   - `\r\n` OR
   - `\r`
3. `|`: OR condition in RegEx
4. `\n`: Match `\n`
5. `{2,}`: Match previous character/s two or more times
6. `g`: Global flag
7. `$1`: The first captured group I.e a single line-break character supported by OS.