# Modify my regex so that pattern search should not be case sensitive

Tags: php, regex

I have following php code that removes whole word that matches the pattern

```
$patterns = ["re", "get", "ER"];
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";
$alternations = implode('|', $patterns);
$re = '(?!(?<=\s)(?:'.$alternations.')(?=\s))\S*(?:'.$alternations.')\S*';
$string = preg_replace('#'.$re.'#', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#\h{2,}#', ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

I want two modifications

1. The pattern search should not be case sensitive e.g. the pattern **ER** must remove **better** in **$string**
2. If removed word in **$string** have line breaks before or after it, only one line break should be removed.

If **$string** is

```
You are definitely getting
better
today
```

Output must be

```
You definitely
today
```

[Sample PHP Code](https://ideone.com/aSp0oY)

Regards,

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/Q00Q8M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all line-breaks, but except only one break?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663750/remove-all-line-breaks-but-except-only-one-break)

Comment: Both of your questions have answers here.

Comment: @Code_Ninja If OP means to match an optional line break at the start of the pattern, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663750/) does not seem helpful.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew your modifications work perfectly, please write it in answer.

Comment: @DMP Posted with a bit of explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$patterns = ["re", "get", "ER"];
$string = "You are definitely getting\nbetter\ntoday";
$alternations = implode('|', $patterns);
$re = '\R?(?!(?<=\s)(?:'.$alternations.')(?=\s))\S*(?:'.$alternations.')\S*';
$string = preg_replace('#'.$re.'#i', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#\h{2,}#', ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Q00Q8M).

While the `i` modifier provides the case insensitivity to regex matching, another, less obvious thing here is that you  need to add an *optional line break pattern*.

That line break can be matched in various ways, but in PHP PCRE, you may easily match it with `\R` construct.

Adding a `?` quantifier after it, you may make it match 1 or 0 times, i.e. make it optional, so that the whole pattern could still match at the start of the string.