# Text file downloaded through browser is without linebreaks

Tags: php, unix

I created and saved a text file(containing simple text) in windows then uploaded it to the unix server, apache/mysql/php and then created a download page with the following code

```
$path = 'myfile.txt';
header ( "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header ( "Content-Length: " . filesize ( $path ) );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $path );

readfile($path);
```

But when I download it by visiting the download page and open the text file in notepad it shows with out the line breaks.

What can I do to solve it ?

Comment: What were the line breaks? I would think it would need the end of line character sequence- \n

Comment: @AshMenhennett That didn't work, the text file simply shows the \n after the line

Comment: Ok, can you change the ```content-type``` to ```text/plain```. Here is some more info on \n: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/6186967

Comment: @AshMenhennett none of those worked, probably because the text file in not created dynamically ?

Comment: Hmmm.. can you set the encoding to ```UTF-8``` aswell as the the earlier suggestions?

Comment: @AshMenhennett nope. nothing.

Comment: Do you think setting the content type to ```text/html``` and using html line breaks in the file would work?

Comment: @AshMenhennett That too didn't work :(

Comment: What client OS are you opening the file in, once downloaded?

Comment: @AshMenhennett Windows.

Comment: ```\r\n``` is the sequence for new line on windows. That should also work for UNIX based systems as well.

Comment: Technically it should, but somehow it isn't. I am thinking to change the format to pdf instead, this is taking to much tome :/

Comment: Welp, you can always firgure it out another day, for now, PDF sounds good :)