# Grunt will only create one file, not multiples

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I've got this really simple Gruntfile that reads a plain text file line by line and is supposed to create an html file of the same name from each line (ie: eng_product_100x100.html) but it only works with one line in the file, not multiples.

This is the console response when trying to run with multiple lines:

```
Running tasks: createProducts

Running "createProducts" task
Writing product/eng/eng_product_100x100.html
eng_product_200x200.html
eng_product_300x300.html
eng_product_400x400.html...ERROR
Warning: Unable to write "product/eng/eng_product_100x100.html
eng_product_200x200.html
eng_product_300x300.html
eng_product_400x400.html" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
  });

  grunt.registerTask('createProducts', 'Create product banners', function() {
    this.async();

    var fs = require('fs');
    var fileName = 'filenames.xml';

    var str = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
    var arr = str.split('/n');
    for (i in arr){
      grunt.file.write(arr[i].split('_')[1]+'/'+arr[i].split('_')[0]+'/'+arr[i], 'test');
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }

  });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Gruntfile.js` is almost correct. The reason why it is not working with multiple lines is due to the line of code reading:

```js
var arr = str.split('/n');
```

**Note** the `/n` should be `\r\n` for a newline character. See [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) for the differences between DOS vs. Unix line endings  That line of code should read:

```js
var arr = str.split('\r\n');
```

**Gruntfile.js**

Here is the full corrected version of the `Gruntfile.js`, including some refactoring:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    });

    grunt.registerTask('createProducts', 'Create product banners', function() {
        this.async();

        var fs = require('fs'),
            fileNameList = 'filenames.txt',
            str = fs.readFileSync(fileNameList, 'utf8'),
            arr = str.split('\r\n');

        for (var i in arr) {
            var newFilePath = arr[i].split('_')[1] + '/' + arr[i].split('_')[0] + '/' + arr[i] + '.html';
            grunt.file.write(newFilePath, '<html></html>');
            console.log('Created file: ' + newFilePath);
        }
    });

};
```

The notable changes after refactoring are:

1. It reads the list from a `filenames.txt` rather than 'filenames.xml' *(There's no need for the file to be `.xml` if it's just plain text as mentioned in your question.*
2. Added a new variable named `newFilePath` as it clearly indicates what all the `arr[i].split()` etc is really creating.
3. Add `'.html'` to the `newFilePath` variable so the resultant files include a `.html` suffix.

---

**UPDATE** Updated answer to utilize `\r\n` to handle both DOS vs. Unix Line Endings.

---

**UPDATE 2**

**Cross Platform Robustness**

The above solution works successfully when `filenames.txt` is created on Windows. However, if `filenames.txt` is created on another OS it can potentially fail because of the various line endings that are used, either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/1611459). To ensure the solution is more robust across different OS/platforms then a check for which line ending is used will be necessary before `split()` is utilized to make an array.

The following shows how to achieve that *(Note: The gist is intentionally verbose for explanation purposes, and should probably be refactored)*:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    });

    grunt.registerTask('createProducts', 'Create product banners', function() {
        this.async();

        var fs = require('fs'),
            fileNameList = 'filenames.txt',
            str = fs.readFileSync(fileNameList, 'utf8'),
            arr = [];

        // Warn if filename.txt does not include any text.
        if (!str) {
            console.warn('Error: ' + fileNameList + ' is empty');
            process.exit(1);
        }

        // Check which line ending is used before splitting.
        if (str.indexOf('\r\n') !== -1) { // CR + LF - filenames.txt was created on Windows.
            arr = str.split('\r\n');
        } else if (str.indexOf('\n') !== -1) { // LF - filenames.txt was created on Unix/Mac OS X.
            arr = str.split('\n');
        } else if (str.indexOf('\r') !== -1) { // CR - filenames.txt was created on Mac OS before X.
            arr = str.split('\r');
        } else { // Only one line exists in filenames.txt
            arr.push(str);
        }

        for (var i in arr) {
            var newFilePath = arr[i].split('_')[1] + '/' + arr[i].split('_')[0] + '/' + arr[i];
            grunt.file.write(newFilePath, '<html></html>');
            console.log('Created file: ' + newFilePath);
        }
    });

};
```