# \r\n vs \n\r what is the difference in their behavior?

Tags: java, string, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I was referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) question and understood that \n moves the cursor to next line without resetting it while \r resets the cursor but not move it to next line. And \r\n used as a new line char in Windows. 
So just out of curiosity, I assigned `\r\n` and `\n\r` to strings along with some other value in Java and printed them in console in my Windows environment.

```
System.out.println("ABC\r\nDEF");
System.out.println("ABC\n\rDEF");
```

### Output 1:

```
ABC
DEF
```

As per my understanding, here `\r` just did reset the cursor and moved it at the beginning of the same line (line 1) and `\n` advanced it to the next line (line 2). Hence `DEF` printed in new line.

### Output 2:

```
ABC

DEF
```

But I am not able to understand the Output 2. I assume this one should be same as output 1 because if `\n` advances the cursor to next line (line 2) and then if `\r` reset it and puts it at the beginning of the same line (line 2 in this case may be) then why `DEF` is not printed at line 2?

### Edit:

This is the additional question which is not covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them

Comment: @Obenland this extra question isn't asked or answered there.

Comment: @Obenland your link only mentions that Windows supports `\r\n`. But Windows also supports only `\n` and only `\r`. Hence I got this question and which is not answered in the link you mentioned or XtremeBaumer mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Java and everything to do with the console/terminal/etc. that's converting the output to a display.

In Windows command windows, the canonical "end-of-line" encoding is `\r\n`. Windows treats this as a single entity.

Although the historical reason for this is a teleprinter's carriage return (move the print head to the left) and newline (advance the paper one line), in Windows `\r\n` is one "thing" as far as display is concerned.

`\n\r` is not recognised as one "thing" in the same way. But it handles each character by advancing by a line.

Comment: Thanks @slim for the answer. But if `\n\r` is processed as 2 separate things and I also tried passing `\n` alone and `\r` alone and both of them are able to print chars on new line. So are we used to pass `\r\n` together just to follow the preset standards or can we also use one of `\n` or `\r` alone also? Is it considered as a bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `\n\r` doesn't exist, but `\r\n` does. The reason, way back in the day, is that hardware like the ASR-33 that had a 'carriage' could overlap the carriage return with the line feed *if* the carriage return came first. Using `\n\r` would have been extremely inefficient, so nobody did it.

So don't do it.

Comment: Interesting. So the ASR-33 would advance the paper while the carriage was returning, if it received a `LF` during that action, but it would not return the carriage until the paper had advanced if it received a `CR` during that action.

Comment: That's what I said. Also the numerous moving-head dot-matrix printers.

Comment: Thanks - just clarifying what was meant by "overlap".

Comment: Ohk, thanks @EJP and slim. Now I got it, learnt something new.

Comment: @slim What else could it mean?

Comment: Carriage return took a lot longer to complete than line feed on an ASR-33, hence the reason for the special handling. I think I remember if you sent "/n/rA" the teletype would print 'A' while the carriage was returning, i.e., somewhere in the middle of the page.