# VS Code: End of file new line not persisting

Tags: newline, visual-studio-code

I am facing an irritating problem that no new line is being saved for HTML and JavaScript despite explicitly setting that they should be done. Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/imyousuf/fs-image-manager)

Visual Studio Code version details:

```
Version 1.23.0
Commit 7c7da59c2333a1306c41e6e7b68d7f0caa7b3d45
Date 2018-05-03T15:23:19.356Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```

VS Code Settings:

[image: Settings of my Visual Studio Code]

Comment: You've shown the user settings.  can we assume you have nothing, or nothing conflicting, in your workspace settings?  Which override user settings.

Comment: The settings look correct. You can try to run VS Code without the extensions `code --disable-extensions` to make sure that this is not the action of one of the extensions. You can also check whether these settings work in VS Code Insiders (https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Comment: @Mark Yes my Workspace settings is completely empty

Comment: @VictorS. When I start extensions disabled, the end of file new line does work as expected. How do I debug and identify the exact extension causing it?

Comment: @VictorS. NVM, I actually started uninstalling the unused extensions and removing a particular one actually solved the problem by uninstalling [this plugin](https://github.com/lonefy/vscode-js-css-html-formatter). Thank you once again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was not in the settings but in the extensions. As pointed out in a comment in the question by VictorS., running the editor in `code --disable-extensions` I validated that without extensions it does work. Then I started uninstalling extensions until it works and finally zero'd down to [this plugin](https://github.com/lonefy/vscode-js-css-html-formatter) and uninstalling it made things work as I was expecting.

Comment: Actually starting with those that format code might help you zero in on the offending extension faster

Answer (score 28):

That's because of a default setting in CODE

```
  // When enabled, insert a final new line at the end of the file when saving it.
  "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
```

Turn that to true and you'll be able to persist a new line. I'd also recommend that your turn on the trimmer for more than one new lines at the end.

- **STEP #1**: Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> on Windows/Linux) to open settings.
- **STEP #2**: Add the following two settings.

  "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
  "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,

[image: VSCode.pro setting]

> ⚡ Here's a GIF Demo — *Save a file to add a line or trim extra lines*

[image]

Comment: If you read through the comments in the question and the accepted answer (which I answered on behalf of VictorS and he deserves the bounty IMO, but I can't reward it against a comment); my settings were correct, but a plugin causes that to override (which might be a bug in itself on that plugin).

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: How to disable vscode for automaticlly adding newline to js files? I use prettier-eslint

Answer (score 3):

It's the wrong setting.

The correct setting is

```
"files.insertFinalNewline": false,
```

setting this to `true` will enable a new line to be added when saving the file.
There is an even more explicit setting `"html.format.endWithNewline": false,` but I've never used that so I am unsure how it works.

Comment: There is no way to update that on the default setting from within the app. When I tried to override it, it sets the new value on the user space (on the right side)

Comment: @imyousuf that's how VS Code settings, work. When you override it'll be in the User Settings. You can't override the default-default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `files.eol` to be `\r\n`. I'm no expert, but since you're on Linux, you might want to try the Linux-specific EOL-marker `\n`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/9770311)

Comment: Actually if you notice the default is LF, but since that did not work, I also tried overriding it with CRLF without any luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to the extensions in vs code and delete the extension called save on typing and delete it and everything will be good to go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).