# apps script getPlainBody gets undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know what happened. I thought this script was working at one point. Now I just keep getting "cannot call method 'split' of undefined".

```
function getVulture(){
  var newSub = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx').getSheetByName('newS');
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('mail');
  var threads = label.getThreads();  
  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) 
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) 
    { 
      var date = messages[j].getDate();
      var fullname = messages[j].getPlainBody().split('Name: ')[1].split('\n')[0];
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label).moveToArchive();
  }
```

The plainbody text is:

Subscription date: May 10, 2018 01:36 pm

Name: Adam West

E-mail Address*: email@g.com

How is this not defined? It's strange because it actually does what I want ... except since there is an error, it never moves on to the `threads[i].removeLabel(label).moveToArchive();` line of code.

Comment: Do more and better debugging, using `console` and editing your code to perform one operation per line.

Comment: As @tehhowch mentioned, try adding logger to debug the issue. Looks like you are receiving some unexpected input which does not contain 'Name:' part.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having trouble with the split("\n") method as it is not always necessary that a new line can be inserted by using "\n" only.

Please refer to what the difference is between "\n" and "\r" and how it used on different platforms.

[Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

[\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

You'll have to use the trail and error method of finding the solution to your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Error has nothing to do with the end of line characters. Still get the same error when I do `var fullname = messages[j].getPlainBody().split('Name: ')[1]`