# How to export string to text file with linebreak? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, line-breaks, notepad

I have function when you import a text file like this
[image]

the date will be formatted to this
[image]
and it will automatically exports a notepad that contains the new formatted date

but the thing is the line break is not working
the newly exported notepad is like this
[image]

my code for the string is

```
   var fileText = $scope.list[0]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[1]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[2]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[3]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[4]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[5]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[6]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[7]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[8]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[9]+"\n"
      +$scope.list[10]+"\n";
```

is there any other way to insert a line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
'\r\n'
```

instead of

```
'\n'
```

For the explanation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them).