# Replace() method not working within function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a function that accepts a plain text file and then returns a list of words in that file. Obviously, I would like to get rid of any newline '\n', however, when using '.replace()' nothing happens.

Function:

```
textfile = 'name.txt'

def read_words(filename):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    message = f.read()
    a = message.replace('\n', '')
    wordlist = a.split(' ')
    print(wordlist)

read_words(textfile)
```

Sample txt:

```
This\n\nis\n\n\na\n\n\nmy\n\nwfile with spaces and blanks
```

My output:

```
['This\\n\\nis\\n\\n\\na\\n\\n\\nmy\\n\\nwfile', 'with', 'spaces', 'and', 'blanks']
```

Why is the '.replace()' method not working?

Comment: Please always use a generic [python] tag for python questions

Comment: What isnt working? This code seems fine to me

Comment: The `replace` method is certainly working. What's your expected output?

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with my IDE. I use 'Thonny'

Comment: New line can be `\n`, `\r\n` or  `\r` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them. How about using the built-in function `readlines()` instead to read a file and split the content by newline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list? Afterward, you can do something like `[ line.split() for line in lines ]`

Comment: _Why is the `'.replace()'` method not working?_ Show us the output that makes you think it isn't working.  You've only shown us the sample file contents, which doesn't demonstrate anything.

Comment: Does your sample text contain the *two-character* `\n`?  That's the only reason replace wouldn't work.

Comment: Is sample txt literally the string `This\n\nis\n\n\na\n\n\nmy\n\nwfile with spaces and blanks`, or are you replacing the newlines with `\n` for us? If the former, you'll need to escape the backslash in your replace: `message.replace('\\n', '')`

Comment: How does one input the single character '\n' in a txt file?

Comment: Hit enter. The `\n` escape in a string literal stands for a line break character.

Comment: @Okeh Worked well and fine for me (Spyder & PyCharm IDEs). Got the following output `['Thisisamywfile', 'with', 'spaces', 'and', 'blanks']`

Comment: I have been misled in thinking the two character '\n' is the same as the one character '\n'. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I love this thread. No downvotes, no snarkiness, just help for a new programmer learning the ropes.

Comment: @DillonDavis Happy to accept an answer of yours if you post one

Comment: @Okeh does `.split()` not work?

Comment: Why do not you add one line to the function to see what exactly is the content of the variable? Add one more debug line there `print("{} --- {}".format(message,type(message)))`. The `.split("\n", "")` method works. The error is in the contents of the variable `message`. Try this: `message.replace("\n","").replace("\r","")`

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is solved, I did not notice. :) Then I can only advise this: `message.replace("\\n","").replace("\n","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current text replacement is that `\` is considered an escape character- the literal characters `\n` are interpreted as a newline character instead. To solution to this is to escape the `\` character itself, via `\\`. Your updated replace statement would then read:

```
a = message.replace('\\n', '')
```

instead of:

```
a = message.replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be case that python or some other programming languages reads **new line as '\n' escape character**. So when python reads your file '\n' means new line and '\\n' means actual '\n' character you wrote in the text file.

So you need to replace like 
`a = message.replace('\\n', '')`