# Why is my txt file not exporting with newlines properly?

Tags: python, django

I know how to make and read from txt files in python, but it's not working properly when I do it as an `HttpResponse` in django.

```
def abc(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    filename = "my-file.txt"
    text_string = ''
    for user in users:
        text_string += '{} {}\n'.format(user.id, user.username)
    print(text_string)  # prints properly in the terminal with a new line
    response = HttpResponse(text_string, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(filename)
    return response
```

This file downloads just fine, but the content looks like this when opened:

```
1 userA2 userB3 userC
```

But I am expecting it to look like:

```
1 userA
2 userB
3 userC
```

Another odd thing I noticed is when I copy / paste the contents in this text editor, it retains the new lines I'm expecting, but is not displaying it as I want in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `text_string += '{} {}\n'.format(user.id, user.username)` to `text_string += '{} {}\r\n'.format(user.id, user.username)`

See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: It works! Thanks! Figured I might have had to do something wonky with `open(file, 'a')`, because that's the only way it worked **properly"* for me before.