# Why is my program printing values without a corresponding print statement?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, replit

I am trying to figure out how to read in a series of values from a file in java. The file has multiple lines and the values are separated with commas in each line. While writing a test program just to figure out how to use a delimiter with Scanner I ran into an issue with my program printing values from the file. I don't know where the program is getting instructions to print all the values from.

This is what is in my public static void main (inside a try loop):

```
File f1 = new File("Data1.txt");
File test = new File("test.txt");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(f1);
Scanner testReader = new Scanner(test);
testReader.useDelimiter(",");

System.out.println("line 18 "+testReader.nextInt());
System.out.println("line 19 "+testReader.nextInt());
System.out.println("line 20 "+testReader.next());
System.out.println("line 21 "+testReader.nextInt());
```

The file I am reading from is test.txt:

```
4,5,6 
7 
8,9,10
```

And this is what is being printed:

```
line 18 4
line 19 5
line 20 6
7
8
line 21 9
```

Comment: Because the file contains `,6\n7\n8,` - note the location of commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scanner is not seeing the linefeed characters as delimiters. This is the reason why the linefeed characters get returned by `scanner.next()`

Solution is to configure the scanner to have space and comma as delimiters:

```
testReader.useDelimiter("(,|\\s)");
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more info on patterns like `"(,|\\s)"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new-line characters as well to the delimiter pattern:

```
testReader.useDelimiter(",|(\r\n)|(\n)");
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, I presume \n represents a newline character, but what does \r represent?

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n` to represent new-line, while Linux/MacOS use `\n`.

Comment: @Ganlas [\r\n, \r and \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)