# Rendering markdown inside of <textarea> adds newline

Tags: html, django, markdown, newline

I am implementing a Wikipedia-like webapp with Django. Data for the different entries is stored in Markdown files on the server. I use markdown2 for the conversions. Everything works just fine but I run into a problem when I try to edit an existing entry. The server serves "edit.html" to the client, passing a django form populated with the existing data.

**views.py**

```
class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, label="title")
   content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label="content"

def edit(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = SearchForm(request.POST) ## a form with only a "title" input

      if form.is_valid():
         title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
         content = util.get_entry(title) ## read the existing file.md
         form = EditPageForm(initial={
            "title": title,
            "content": content
         })
         return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "title": title,
            "form": form
         })
```

**edit.html**

```
   <h1>Edit content for "{{ title }}"</h1>
   <form action="{% url 'save' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }} ## undesired newlines added here
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
   </form>
```

When the browser renders the textarea which includes the data to be edited, newlines are inserted without my consent. This behaviour loops everytime I edit a text so that more and more newlines are added. I don't really understand what is going on. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Python [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) allows to print a string while escaping every special character, very handy for debugging!
I discovered that my code - for some obscure reason - was doubling up on newlines by adding the sequence [`\r\r\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them). So in the end I just used regex to get rid of all the undesired characters at every edit. I consequently modified the following in **views.py**:

```
# read the existing file.md and substitute all undesired characters
content = re.sub('(\r\r\n)+', '\n', util.get_entry(title))
```

Hope it will benefit someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I like to think it is a bug/feature in the converter. I had the same issue, the empty lines in the text area grew exponentially upon repeated submits(in the edit view). Couldn't find any reason for this behavior.

If you try converting to HTML yourself it maybe that you get a different result, but I myself really did not want to go through the pain of regex.

However, the project still received a passing grade when I submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same project CS50X and experienced the same issue.
Unfortunately [@lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11851398/lukas-gamard) solution did not work for me.

My solution was to fix the the way the files were saved in `utils.py` and in particular the `save_entry` function. I modified it to this:

```
default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content.encode('ascii')))
```

This stopped the doubling of CR's and LF's.

Thanks to Doug Forbes for the solution