# NodeJS req.body of textarea return different new line type from read file

Tags: javascript, node.js, newline, body-parser

Currently, I'm working with hashing string related which required the string to be precise(even the new line symbols).

For example I have the following code to read:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GetSet {
  uint256 private total;
  mapping(address => uint256) private numbers;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private heavyArr;

  function getTotal() external view returns (uint256) {
    return total;
  }

  function setNumber(uint256 _num) external returns (bool) {
    total = total - numbers[msg.sender] + _num;
    numbers[msg.sender] = _num;
    return true;
  }

  function setHeavy() external returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      heavyArr[i] = heavyArr[i] + 1;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function getNumber(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
    return numbers[_user];
  }
}
```

I tried to get this content when I pasted it into the textarea on the form and receive it from req.body in NodeJs. I already used

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

After that I printed with
[image]

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(contractCode));
```

to see the new line symbol, it return the following:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\r\npragma solidity ^0.8.0;\r\n\r\ncontract GetSet {\r\n  uint256 private total;\r\n  mapping(address => uint256) private numbers;\r\n  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private heavyArr;\r\n\r\n  function getTotal() external view returns (uint256) {\r\n    return total;\r\n  }\r\n\r\n  function setNumber(uint256 _num) external returns (bool) {\r\n    total = total - numbers[msg.sender] + _num;\r\n    numbers[msg.sender] = _num;\r\n    return true;\r\n  }\r\n\r\n  function setHeavy() external returns (bool) {\r\n    for(uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {\r\n      heavyArr[i] = heavyArr[i] + 1;\r\n    }\r\n    return true;\r\n  }\r\n\r\n  function getNumber(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {\r\n    return numbers[_user];\r\n  }\r\n}

The second one is when I put the code in the file and read from it with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync('GetSet.sol', 'utf8')));
```

It return the following:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\npragma solidity ^0.8.0;\n\ncontract GetSet {\n  uint256 private total;\n  mapping(address => uint256) private numbers;\n  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private heavyArr;\n\n  function getTotal() external view returns (uint256) {\n    return total;\n  }\n\n  function setNumber(uint256 _num) external returns (bool) {\n    total = total - numbers[msg.sender] + _num;\n    numbers[msg.sender] = _num;\n    return true;\n  }\n\n  function setHeavy() external returns (bool) {\n    for(uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {\n      heavyArr[i] = heavyArr[i] + 1;\n    }\n    return true;\n  }\n\n  function getNumber(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {\n    return numbers[_user];\n  }\n}

as you can see, the return strings from textarea req.body and the read file are different with new line symbol(req.body have `\r\n` while read file only have `\n`)
I don't understand why the 2 ways of getting the text return different results, and how to make them similar(because I need them to be similar to match the hash string every time). I searched and there doesn't seem to be any answer on why textarea/req.body has a different new line symbol so currently I'm kinda stuck on this issue.

The only thing I was able to look up is this which explain what those new line symbols mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433263/11225821