# Uri.Parse() is adding random characters inside the uri

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I try to create a Uri object using `Uri.parse`, I get **%0D%0A** added after `_countryCode` value

[image: value of _countryCode is appended by %0D%0A]

```bash
This is what gets logged

 http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?country=US%0D%0A&username=medcollapp
```

value of _countryCode is a string like US or IN.
_countryCode is not empty I made sure of it.

I have no idea how to fix this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the _countryCode value ?

Comment: Its a string value like US or IN, thanks for reminding me i forget to mention the value

Comment: if you printed it before the Uri.parse method, what value is typed in the console ?

Comment: you country code is US\r\n - you have to remove that two "line endings" - more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433225/2252830

Comment: Before parsing expected url gets printed : http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?country=US&username=medcollapp

Comment: pskin i dont follow you, after printing the url string there are no \r\n

Comment: Post code, not screenshots.

Comment: @ShantanuBorkar `\r\n` are whitespace characters (carriage return and linefeed).  You probably would not notice them when printing them directly, and they get converted to `%0D%0A` when encoded as an URL.  Use `_countryCode.trim()` first.

Comment: @jamesdlin _countryCode.trim() worked. Thank you very much and thanks to everyone who responded  \(@^0^@)/