# Only "cat" command doesn't print any output after getting shell by pwntool

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, exploit, pwntools

I was making a simple CTF(Capture The Flag) problem with docker. The current case is simple(It's not a real problem, it's just a test.); enter a specified string and get a shell(`/bin/bash`) if correct.

The original C source code is here. If the user's input is exactly `1n1tTheJourney2Pwnable`, the program runs `get_shell()` which gives `/bin/sh` to the user.

```
// welcome.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void alarm_handler() {
    puts("TIME OUT");
    exit(-1);
}
void initialize() {
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    alarm(30);
}

void get_shell() {
  char *cmd = "/bin/sh";
  char *args[] = {cmd, NULL};

  execve(cmd, args, NULL);
}

int main() {
    char buf[32];

    initialize();
    printf("input: ");
    scanf("%s", buf);

    if(strcmp(buf,"1n1tTheJourney2Pwnable") == 0) {
        printf("SUCCESS!!\n");
        get_shell();
    } else {
        printf("Wrong..!!\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` for the problem.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
# user name and the title of the problem are identical
ENV user welcome
ENV port 2023

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y
RUN apt-get install -y socat gcc

RUN adduser $user

WORKDIR /home/$user


ADD ./$user.c   /home/$user/$user.c
ADD ./flag      /home/$user/flag

RUN gcc -o /home/$user/$user /home/$user/$user.c

RUN chown $user:$user /home/$user/$user
RUN chown $user:$user /home/$user/flag
RUN chmod 755 /home/$user/$user
RUN chmod 750 /home/$user/flag

USER $user
EXPOSE $port
CMD socat -T 30 TCP-LISTEN:$port,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:/home/$user/$user
```

I build that `Dockerfile` as below:

```
sudo docker build -t system_welcome <dockerfile location>
sudo docker run -p 2023:2023 system_welcome
```

Of course, this problem is very easy as just typing the following string after establishing a connection by hitting the command `nc 127.0.0.1 2023`. However, I wanted to demonstrate the basic usage of `pwntool`. So I wrote a simple script doing so.

```py
from pwn import context, remote, process

context.log_level = 'debug'

#p = process('./welcome')
p = remote('127.0.0.1', 2023)

p.recvuntil(b'input: ')
p.sendline(b'1n1tTheJourney2Pwnable')

p.interactive()
```

So, the program does work as expected and obtains the shell(`/bin/sh`). However, as suggested in the picture below, the shell doesn't print anything as a result of `cat` commands, even though the interactive program received the data. Oddly, results from other commands like `id` or `ls` are being shown correctly.
[image]

It's highly expected of `pwntool`'s problem or `Dockerfile`'s problem, but I couldn't find any solution or tips to resolve this problem, so I need some help related to this.

Comment: It actually prints to docker and content goes to docker logs.
Default console from docker-containers goes to docker logs.

Comment: @fly2matrix   However, I observe the docker log of that container, there is nothing related to the output from the command [cat]. Only information related to signals from the program(welcome.c) that is designed to shut down automatically after 30 seconds since the start.

I don't think the command results aren't printed to docker itself... (Tbh, I don't know what's wrong.)

Comment: try something like this :  docker run -p 2023:2023 -t system_welcome

Comment: @fly2matrix I'm sorry but I don't know what's different from my options written on the question... (I also tried your suggestion, but it was to no avail.)

Comment: @fly2matrix I solved my problem. The main cause was related to delimiters. You can check my answer if you're interested.

Comment: BTW, `cat` _does_ still copy binary output from its stdin (or command-line-argument files) to stdout even if that content isn't a well-formed text file (which as you noted requires a newline at the end of each line of text); there'd need to be something else in play for that output not to be read or visible. The `'\r\n'` will cause the cursor to go back to the beginning of the line during the process of printing, but it doesn't stop that printing from taking place.

Comment: (Mind, if something you do adds _extra_ content, a cursor at the beginning of the line without a newline to cause it to be moved down can lead to whatever was there before the move-to-the-left to be overwritten; alternately, Windows only puts CRLFs _between_ lines, not _after_ lines, so a one-line file won't have one any CRLF sequence at all; but in the general case, where you aren't using something like `while read` expected to process the last line, just `cat`ting a file with Windows newlines works well enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was the difference between `\r\n` and `\n`. In the content of the previous question, `pwntool` received the string data with a delimiter of `\r\n`, which is used as a new line character in Windows OS. However, I was using Linux(Ubuntu 22.04@WSL2 on Windows 11).

After inspection, I found `flag` wasn't written on Linux whose delimiter is `\n`. (Assumably it would be created in Windows or Mac OS.)

So, I deleted my `flag` file with `\r\n` delimiter and created the `flag` file again in Linux entirely. After revision, everything worked as I intended and expected.

[image]

The main cause of the problem was near but I couldn't see for nearly 18 hours(Yeah, it may sound hilarious.). I hope my case would be helpful who having troubles with similar problems with mine. To conclude, neither Docker nor the "pwn" posed any issues.

More to read: [What is the difference between \r\n, \r, and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/what-is-the-difference-between-r-n-r-and-n)